# Can I delete/hide unnecessary INFO:CONSOLE messages in my log?

Tags: python-2.7, logging, console

I am currently running code that is working great, but I'm having something that is bugging me a bit and it is unnecessary info messages in my terminal.

My code is script that is running on a website and the messages say "The SSL Certificate used to load resources from https://www.paypal.com will be distrusted in the future. Once, distrusted...

None if this is important to me. Is there any way to take it out so my console log is clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You should rise root logger level to WARNING, ERROR or CRITICAL. Log level controls what kind of logs you want to see. WARNING is not error, but may lead to some unexpected results in app, ERROR is self explaining as well as CRITICAL.

You can set different level for class or package level.

```
The root logger must specify a level and a list of handlers. An example of a root logger section is given below.

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=hand01
The level entry can be one of DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL or NOTSET. For the root logger only, NOTSET means that all messages will be logged. Level values are eval()uated in the context of the logging package’s namespace.
```